matplotlib: failed to plot time series bars at the right timeframe
Basically, i have the following data below from 9am to 1pm on a particular date. When I tried to create a time series bar plot, the bars are overlapping each other and the plot kept displaying a timeframe that is way wider than the 9am -1pm window. How to fix this using matplotlib without seaborn?
Note that the data columns are already in the following format End_Datetime datetime64[ns] and VOLUME float64. And if i were to do a line plot, there would be no issues but if I do a bar plot, the bars overlapped and the times are just out of place.
{'End_Datetime': {0: Timestamp('2024-02-29 09:14:59.999000'),
  1: Timestamp('2024-02-29 09:29:59.999000'),
  2: Timestamp('2024-02-29 09:44:59.999000'),
  3: Timestamp('2024-02-29 09:59:59.999000'),
  4: Timestamp('2024-02-29 10:14:59.999000'),
  5: Timestamp('2024-02-29 10:29:59.999000'),
  6: Timestamp('2024-02-29 10:44:59.999000'),
  7: Timestamp('2024-02-29 10:59:59.999000'),
  8: Timestamp('2024-02-29 11:14:59.999000'),
  9: Timestamp('2024-02-29 11:29:59.999000'),
  10: Timestamp('2024-02-29 11:44:59.999000'),
  11: Timestamp('2024-02-29 11:59:59.999000'),
  12: Timestamp('2024-02-29 12:14:59.999000'),
  13: Timestamp('2024-02-29 12:29:59.999000'),
  14: Timestamp('2024-02-29 12:44:59.999000'),
  15: Timestamp('2024-02-29 12:59:59.999000'),
  16: Timestamp('2024-02-29 13:14:59.999000'),
  17: Timestamp('2024-02-29 13:29:59.999000'),
  18: Timestamp('2024-02-29 13:44:59.999000')},
 'VOLUME': {0: 45000.0,
  1: 142000.0,
  2: 55000.0,
  3: 39000.0,
  4: 66000.0,
  5: 32000.0,
  6: 28000.0,
  7: 30000.0,
  8: 21000.0,
  9: 18000.0,
  10: 61000.0,
  11: 154000.0,
  12: 33000.0,
  13: 24000.0,
  14: 13000.0,
  15: 12000.0,
  16: 339000.0,
  17: 31000.0,
  18: 281000.0}}


fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols = 1,dpi=600, figsize=(12,9))
ax.bar(x=df['End_Datetime'], height = df['VOLUME'].values, color = 'blue', label = '15 mins Bin Volume', edgecolor = 'white', alpha=0.5)
ax.set_ylabel('Volume')
ax.legend(fontsize=6, title_fontsize=8, loc='upper left')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
fig.tight_layout()
fig.show()



If I understand correctly your issue, I would first set your data into a DataFrame with columns "Date" and "Volume" (or whatever).
Then, you can easily plot your timeseries using Seaborn (sns)
import seaborn as sns
sns.lineplot(data = df, x = "Date", y = "Volume")

Note that:
You might need to convert Date into a timestamp using
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])


it's already converted to pandas datetime

Then, you should be able to visualize your timeseries using the code I have provided to you. I have tried on my own with your data and it works properly.

i am trying to do a barplot. I want to do it using matplotlib.

Then, you can proceed by calling sns.barplot instead of lineplot.
Seaborn is built on matplotlib and is much more easier to use.
If you really want to use matplotlib purely, you will need to define a bar_width and call :
ax.bar(df["End_Datetime"], df["VOLUME"], width = bar_width...).
You can either set a dynamic width using the difference between two consecutive timestamps, or set a fix width by trying a few time and improving the result.
